# ASP.net Invalid postback or callback argument - locate control causing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

We are getting the following error from one of our applications.  There is no pattern to the error, last night we logged 3 of the, sometimes we go days without any of them.  I know there is an issue somewhere and don't want to ignore it, since problems get worse on their own, not better.

Unfortunately, the error message does not indicate the control causing the issue, which is what I would like to find.  Have read through the many posts about this topic, but nothing applies.  We are not using JS to modify drop-down lists or other controls, event validation is enabled and we are not turning it off, no nested  tags, cannot find any mal-formed tags, etc.  If I could see what control on the page is triggering it, that would help run down what could be causing it.

We are capturing the following in our error log from the exception:

```
InnerException.Message
GetBaseException()
Request.Url
```

Thanks in advance!

Message:

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

Details:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Checked another of the logged entries and this one is different.  It fails on a LinkButton, whereas the one above shows TextBox as the fail point.  At least I think that is the case.  Does that mean a change to a Textbox (for the above one), triggered the postback?  I checked that form and there are no textboxes configured with OnTextChanged.

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Meant to say no nested form tags.

Comment: Can you capture the postback request from Fiddler? With this on hand you can understand what went wrong with your form.

Comment: We can try, but the error occurs very randomly.  It is almost as if the user is doing some combination of things on the site and then the validation error is triggered.  Unfortunately, we have not been able to replicate.

Comment: Have Fiddler running and capturing on the page.  I can see the postback values.  Page did not generate a validation error, so I don't think I will see anything in the capture out of the ordinary.  If I could replicate the error, I would have a chance.

Comment: I see, if the issue is hard to reproduce. You need to log whole POST request match it with the issue you got. You can enable logging at ASP.NET - so you might consider updating your logging on error code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865638/logging-server-wide-request-data-including-post-data-in-iis-6-asp-net-webfor. You might enable IIS logs http://serverfault.com/a/90965. Having the failing request on hand you can check what is wrong with the form.

Comment: We have been monitoring the IIS event logs and see the corresponding failures, again they are very random.  I will look at the two links you provided and see what we can implement to help track down the intermittent failures.  Thanks!